# Discord.js SlashCommandBuilder() : get option choices from a list in an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, discord.js, command

I'm trying to create a slash command `/test3` with an option `input` that has choices. However, I'd like to get these choices from an async function, but the way I'm trying to do it isn't working.

Here is the code to generate a simplified version of my argument list, in `tools.js`

```
module.exports = {
    getArgumentList: () => getArgumentList()
}

async function getArgumentList(){
    return [
        {name: '1', value:'One'},
        {name: '2', value:'Two'},
        {name: '3', value:'Three'},
        {name: '4', value:'Four'},
        {name: '5', value:'Five'}
    ]
}
```

And the code for the command, in `test3.js`

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { getArgumentList } = require("../tools.js")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('test3')
            .setDescription('Test command for commands with options.')
            .addStringOption(option =>
                getArgumentList()
                        .then(list => option.setName('input')
                                                .setDescription('The input to echo back.') 
                                                .setChoices(...list) )),           
    async execute(interaction){ 
        console.log('Testing')
    }
}
```

Here I get this error:

```
ExpectedValidationError: Expected
    at InstanceValidator.handle 
    ...
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12) {
  validator: 's.instance(V)',
  given: Promise { <pending> },
  expected: [Function: SlashCommandStringOption]
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Would there be a good way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your command system to have data be a function, and in your slash command deploy script (or wherever you used the data property before) await it, so you can then change data to be this:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: async () => {
        // The list is fetched here (where we can use promises and async-await) before the SlashCommandBuilder gets made.
        const list = await getArgumentList();
        return new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName("test3")
            .setDescription("Test command for commands with options.")
            .addStringOption((option) =>
                option
                    .setName("input")
                    .setDescription("The input to echo back.")
                    .setChoices(...list)
            );
    };
}
```

Example slash command deploy script:

```js
const commands = await Promise.all(
    client.commandRegistry.map((command) => (await command.data()).toJSON())
);
```

You can also pass a default SlashCommandBuilder to the data function now if you want:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: async (b) => {
        // The list is fetched here (where we can use promises and async-await) before the SlashCommandBuilder gets made.
        const list = await getArgumentList();
        // no .setName() required anymore! Deploy script set it for us.
        return b
            .setDescription("Test command for commands with options.")
            .addStringOption((option) =>
                option
                    .setName("input")
                    .setDescription("The input to echo back.")
                    .setChoices(...list)
            );
    };
}
```

```js
const commands = await Promise.all(
    client.commandRegistry.map((command, key) =>
        (await command.data(new SlashCommandBuilder().setName(key))).toJSON()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.then()` function always returns a promise, so you can't set it as the return value of `.addStringOption()`. Using async/await would make this a lot cleaner and easier.

```js
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('test3')
            .setDescription('Test command for commands with options.')
            .addStringOption(async option => {
               let list = await getArgumentList()
               return option.setName('input')
                   .setDescription('The input to echo back.')
                   .setChoices(...list)
            })
```

Comment: An async function always returns a Promise as well...

Comment: @jackssrt in his example, a promise is being passed into a function that doesn't accept a promise